# Clicking enter in dialog not working properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, messagebox

I'm having a weird problem right now with a log in form in my program. Basically if the user enters an incorrect login, and then hits enter in the popup, it closes it and submits the log in form again. Is there a way I can prevent this? So when the user presses enter to close the pop up, the enter press doesn't register on my log in form?

Heres the code from my login form. Button1 is the log in button Thanks!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a username and password!");
        }
        else
        {
            bool loggedin = false;
            for (int i = 0; i <= Program.ProfileList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (Program.ProfileList[i].Username == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    AESEncrypt encrypt = new AESEncrypt();
                    if (Program.ProfileList[i].Password == encrypt.EncryptToString(textBox2.Text))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully logged in!");
                        Program.ActiveUser = textBox1.Text;
                        loggedin = true;
                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!loggedin)
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password!");
            }

        }
    }

    private void textBox2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're saying is happening, but I think your problem lies in the fact that the button specified in `Form.AcceptButton` for your form is the button that gets pressed when you hit the Enter key. So if you don't want that behavior, you need to clear the `Form.AcceptButton` value.

Comment: Additionally, you're not going to get a `KeyUp` for the Enter key if you have the AcceptButton set, although if I recall correctly, you will get a `KeyDown` for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because you used the KeyUp event.  And also pressed the Enter key to dismiss the message box.  Which does it correctly, it uses the KeyDown event.  So the dialog closes, your TextBox gets the focus back and you release the Enter key.  To trigger the  KeyUp event again :)

Also turn on your speakers to hear the nasty DING! you get from the text box not liking the Enter key.

Use the KeyDown event instead:

```
    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
            button1.PerformClick();
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something came up, so I didn't get to try these answers at the time. I just tried yours, and it works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When this problem happens, is focus in the TextBox represented by `textBox2`? This is probably what is happening:

1. The user enters an incorrect username and password.
2. The user presses Enter with focus in the password field.
3. A MessageBox is displayed, indicating the username and password are incorrect.
4. The user presses enter to dismiss the MessageBox.

I'm not positive on this, but most likely the MessageBox is closed when the key down event for the enter key is received. Focus changes back to the login form, specifically to the password field (where focus was before the MessageBox was displayed). The key up event is sent to the control in focus, which is the password field - which triggers the log in check again.

To fix this, remove the key up handler and set the [Form.AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) property to the OK / Login button, and set the [Form.CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx) property to the Cancel button. This will automatically allow enter to press the OK / Login button, and Escape to press the Cancel button.

Comment: I'm almost certian KeyDown & KeyUp events won't go to different windows. That is, you won't get a KeyDown on one window and the associated KeyUp message in a different window.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it as follows.You will also have to set the `KeyPreview` property to true.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key
>   events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text.Trim()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a username and password!");
            }
            else if (IsValidUser(textBox1.Text.Trim(), textBox2.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Succesfully logged in!");
                Program.ActiveUser = textBox1.Text;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password!");
            }
        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                button1.PerformClick();
            }
        }

        private bool IsValidUser(string userName, string userPassword)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= Program.ProfileList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (Program.ProfileList[i].Username == userName)
                {
                    AESEncrypt encrypt = new AESEncrypt();
                    if (Program.ProfileList[i].Password == encrypt.EncryptToString(userPassword))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```